# Why is Latin1_General_CS_AS not case sensitive?

Tags: sql-server, collation

For `LIKE` queries, the *Latin1_General_CS_AS* collation is not case-sensitive. According to a [bug report to Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/725949/case-sensitivity-doesnt-work-when-using-a-range-in-like-with-collate-latin1-general-cs-as), this was listed as "By Design".

However, the *Latin1_General_Bin* collation is also case-sensitive and works exactly as expected for `LIKE` queries.

You can see the difference in this simple query:

```
SELECT
    MyColumn AS Latin1_General_Bin
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%[a-z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin;

SELECT
    MyColumn AS Latin1_General_CS_AS
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%[a-z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3441/1).

---

My questions are:

1. Why would this be considered "By Design" to be case-insensitive in `LIKE`?
2. If this really is better, why is it a different behavior between the two case sensitive collations *_Bin* and *_CS_AS*?

I was going to standardize on *Latin1_General_CS_AS* for any case-sensitive databases going forward, but this seems like a subtle query bug waiting to happen.

Comment: I'm not sure this means that `Latin1_General_CS_AS` is not case sensitive. Changing the query with `LIKE '%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;` seems to work. The problem appears to be with the way that `%[a-z]%` is choosing the characters

Comment: @lamak Same reason as this http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34731. It is documented and by design. The range matches the collation sort order. You can imagine it seeking in on an index with that key column at the start of the range and following the index along until the end of the range returning everything found en route.

Comment: this seems to be a range "problem"... if you use `LIKE '%e%'` or `LIKE 'e'` (suggested in the bug report) you get the exprected result (no), but `LIKE '%[d-f]%'` returns the wrong result (yes)

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for the link. I figured it would be something like that from the connect item.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is not a regular expression. The range `[a-z]` just means `>='a' AND <='z'`.

Under that collation that includes all letters except capital `Z`.

Under `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` all except capital `A` fall within that sort order.

---

In case that is still not clear review the sort orders for the following; for the three different collations

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES ('A'),('B'),('Y'),('Z'), ('a'),('b'),('y'),('z')) V(C)
ORDER BY C COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin
```

You see that the binary collation has all the upper case letters together, the other two don't.

```
+--------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+
| Latin1_General_Bin | Latin1_General_CS_AS | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS  |
+--------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+
| A                  | a                    | A                             |
| B                  | A                    | a                             |
| Y                  | b                    | B                             |
| Z                  | B                    | b                             |
| a                  | y                    | Y                             |
| b                  | Y                    | y                             |
| y                  | z                    | Z                             |
| z                  | Z                    | z                             |
+--------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+
```

[This is documented in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

> In range searches, the characters included in the range may vary
>   depending on the sorting rules of the collation.

Comment: Thanks, that helps clear up why it is behaving like that. But why is that desirable? that would mean that in the **case-sensitive** collation _CS_AS, the word 'zzz' < 'Zaaaa'. Yet that seems counter to every other ASCII based language/comparator. So why would that be desirable?

Comment: @arserbin3 - That seems to be a different question! From the POV of the range in the pattern syntax you can have arbitrary ranges with any character as the start or the end and once you understand the logic it  makes some kind of sense. As for whether it makes any sense for  'zzz' to sort before 'Zaaaa' in a CS collation. Not something I've thought about but why wouldn't you use a CI collation there if you don't want that sorting behaviour?

Comment: @MartinSmith THANK YOU! This really saved me time and cured my frustration. Great work!